# Tobii-Eyetracker with python, unable to print gaze data

Tags: python

I am working on a project that requires the location on a user's eyes on a screen. I followed the tobii-sdk documentation which helps create a very basic program that prints gaze data from my eye tracker. However, when I run the code the gaze data does not print and I am not sure why.

```html
import time
import tobii_research as tr

found_eyetrackers = tr.find_all_eyetrackers()

my_eyetracker = found_eyetrackers[0]
print("Address: " + my_eyetracker.address)
print("Model: " + my_eyetracker.model)
print("Name (It's OK if this is empty): " + my_eyetracker.device_name)
print("Serial number: " + my_eyetracker.serial_number)

def gaze_data_callback(gaze_data):
    # Print gaze points of left and right eye
    print("Left eye: ({gaze_left_eye}) \t Right eye: ({gaze_right_eye})".format(
        gaze_left_eye=gaze_data['left_gaze_point_on_display_area'],
        gaze_right_eye=gaze_data['right_gaze_point_on_display_area']))

my_eyetracker.subscribe_to(tr.EYETRACKER_GAZE_DATA, gaze_data_callback, as_dictionary=True)
time.sleep(5)
my_eyetracker.unsubscribe_from(tr.EYETRACKER_GAZE_DATA, gaze_data_callback)
```

The output i get is:

```html
Address: MY-ADDRESS
Model: IS4_Large_Peripheral
Name (It's OK if this is empty):
Serial number: MY-SERIAL NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use this callback function:

```
def gazeDataCallback(self,startGazeData):
    print(startGazeData)
```

I get output with this format:

```
{'device_time_stamp': 1623291632673972, 'system_time_stamp': 34428318423, 
'left_gaze_point_on_display_area': (nan, nan), 
'left_gaze_point_in_user_coordinate_system': (nan, nan, nan), 
'left_gaze_point_validity': 0, 'left_pupil_diameter': nan,    
'left_pupil_validity': 0, 
'left_gaze_origin_in_user_coordinate_system': (nan, nan, nan), 
'left_gaze_origin_in_trackbox_coordinate_system': (nan, nan, nan), 
'left_gaze_origin_validity': 0, 
'right_gaze_point_on_display_area': (nan, nan), 
'right_gaze_point_in_user_coordinate_system': (nan, nan, nan), 
'right_gaze_point_validity': 0, 
'right_pupil_diameter': nan, 
'right_pupil_validity': 0, 
'right_gaze_origin_in_user_coordinate_system': (nan, nan, nan), 
'right_gaze_origin_in_trackbox_coordinate_system': (nan, nan, nan), 
'right_gaze_origin_validity': 0}
```

I suspect what you need to do is refer to the dictionary with the correct key - i.e.

```
print(gaze_data['left_gaze_point_on_display_area'])
```

instead of

```
print({gaze_left_eye})
```